# Alternative to Esper?

Tags: licensing, esper, complex-event-processing

I am really interested in Complex Event Processing and have been looking at Esper.  However my company has an anti-GPL stance and I was wondering if there are non-GPL alternatives out there under a more business friendly license like Apache or BSD?

Comment: Apache Flink has a CEP module now

Answer (score 7):

Quite late, but here you can find an overview, too. [CEP vendor overview](http://rulecore.com/CEPblog/?page_id=47)

Comment: the link's now broken :-/

Comment: The site can still be accessed via the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20131008031358/http://rulecore.com/CEPblog/?page_id=47).

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, Esper has a non-GPL license if that's what you're after.  Go to their website at www.espertech.com - otherwise the community license is just GPL.

Answer (score 4):

[SiddhiCEP](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/siddhi/) is an Apache License v2 software. You can use that as a library or even as a CEP Server. If you are going for production you can also get production support for SiddhiCEP from the open source product company called [WSO2](http://wso2.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Drools Fusion has an ASL-style license (http://legacy.drools.codehaus.org/Licensing).  Pion is another open-source system with an AGPL license. If you prefer a normal commercial license there's Aleri, Streambase and ruleCore. Aleri and streambase are "normal" software and ruleCore is a CEP cloud.

Comment: If GPL is not-business-friendly, then AGPL is more so. My plain english read of GPL vs AGPL is AGPL prohibits even loose-coupled (not linked) usage of functional with/without an formal API, where the ecosystem is proprietary. Typically when people are looking for business-friendly FOSS, they are basically looking to reap the benefits of open-source without necessarily having to give back any. For all the love-n-affection many corporates show towards Open-source, this is the single biggest motivation, apart from some PR brownie-points.

Answer (score 2):

There is book coming up on CEP; chapter 1 available here for free (no login required) lists a number of systems, but no license information: http://www.manning.com/etzion/Etzion_MEAPch01_free.pdf

Comment: Look at page 28-29, they list the languages for Event Programming.

Comment: This book wasn't that helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at OpenESB's [Intelligent Event Processor](https://open-esb.dev.java.net/IEPSE.html). I have not looked at it in any detail, but I did find it difficult to determine exactly what the underlying API was. Rather, it talks a lot about a NetBeans IDE that allows you define an event processing work-flow, which is ok, but what I would like to understand better is what the real API is underlying the IDE. In contrast, Esper is all about the API and much lighter on the assistive tools.

I am also not sure what the license is, but I assume that as part of the Sun GlassFish initiative, it would be CDDL  (correct acronym ?)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [ERMA (Extremely Reusable Monitoring API)](http://erma.wikidot.com/). It was developed by Orbitz for internal use, and they have open sourced it a while ago. It uses the Apache License.

Answer (score 1):

FYI Esper Enterprise Edition does not use the GPL. I.e. no copy left problem...

> **Can I freely use Esper in my application?**
>
> Esper is licensed under the
>   open source GPL GNU Public License v2.0 license. You may check this
>   license depending on your application and how you redistribute it.
>   Restrictions may apply. You should consider Esper Enterprise Edition
>   for any production use. Esper Enterprise Edition is not made available
>   under a viral copyleft license and combines Esper, EsperJMX, EsperJDBC
>   and Esper Studio in one single certified and supported package for
>   maximal productivity, interoperability and manageability.

Answer (score 0):

The rulecore cep server has a non-gpl (closed) source code license. If you purchase a license from ruleCore, you are allowed to modify the source and distribute your own version without showing your modifies source code to anyone. Might be a good idea for a commercial project with all kinds of IP issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check with Siddhi

https://github.com/wso2/siddhi